# Contact form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

how to create a field like this on contact form 7?

HTML:

```
<select name="topic" id="user-topic" class="m-select">
    <option value="Not select">O que você precisa?</option>
    <option value="Topic 1">Solicitar contato de um vendedor</option>
    <option value="Topic 2">Agendar Revisão</option>
    <option value="Topic 3">Cotação de Peças</option>
<option value="Topic 3">Crítica/Sugestão</option>
```

the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pedrohkms/2amwjd36/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the documentation on the site: http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Example:

[select your-country "China" "India" "San Marino"]